# Change values in CSV or text style file

Tags: python, csv

I'm having some problems with the following file.
Each line has the following content:

```
foobar   1234.569    7890.125     12356.789   -236.4569   236.9874   -569.9844
```

What I want to edit in this file, is reverse last three numbers, positive or negative.
The output should be:

```
foobar   1234.569    7890.125     12356.789   236.4569   -236.9874   569.9844
```

Or even better:

```
foobar,1234.569,7890.125,12356.789,236.4569,-236.9874,569.9844
```

What is the easiest pythonic way to accomplish this?
At first I used the csv.reader, but I found out it's not tab separated, but random (3-5) spaces.
I've read the CSV module and some examples / similar questions here, but my knowledge of python ain't that good and the CSV module seems pretty tough when you want to edit a value of a row.
I can import and edit this in excel with no problem, but I want to use it in a python script, since I have hundreds of these files. VBA in excel is not an option.

Would it be better to just regex each line?
If so, can someone point me in a direction with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split your white-space-separated lines into a row:

```
row = line.split()
```

then use `csv.writer()` to create your new file.

`str.split()` with no arguments, or `None` as the first argument, splits on arbitrary-width whitespace and ignores leading and trailing whitespace on the line:

```
>>> 'foobar   1234.569    7890.125     12356.789   -236.4569   236.9874   -569.9844\n'.split()
['foobar', '1234.569', '7890.125', '12356.789', '-236.4569', '236.9874', '-569.9844']
```

As a complete script:

```
import csv

with open(inputfilename, 'r') as infile, open(outputcsv, 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    for line in infile:
        row = line.split()
        inverted_nums = [-float(val) for val in row[-3:]]
        writer.writerow(row[:-3] + inverted_nums)
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect example, especially the inverted_nums part, which I coded completly wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import neg
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip().split()
        last3 = map(str,map(neg,map(float,line[-3:])))
        print("{0},{1}".format(line[0],','.join(line[1:-3]+last3)))
```

Produces:

```
>>> 
foobar,1234.569,7890.125,12356.789,236.4569,-236.9874,569.9844
```

CSV outputting version:

```
with open('file.txt') as f, open('ofile.txt','w+') as o:
    writer = csv.writer(o)
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip().split()
        last3 = map(neg,map(float,line[-3:]))
        writer.writerow(line[:-3]+last3)
```

Comment: Thanks, great find with the Neg operator. Hadn't seen that one before.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

```
import numpy as np

a=np.genfromtxt('foo.csv', dtype=None)
with open('foo.csv','w') as f:
for el in a[()]:
    f.write(str(el)+',')
```